# tracking down abandoned / idle connections in postgresql

Tags: database, lua, database-connection, postgresql-9.2

**Background Information**

I found a bug in some code we have where a function connects to a postgresql database, but then "returns" out of it before closing the database connection.

This issue was only caught because at one point, we had a huge number of concurrent connections that exceeded the MAX_CONNECTIONS value and I found a bunch of "idle" records in the  pg_stat_activity table

**'Question**

I only see these idle connections if I create a load on the database by looping in my script and calling this function a bunch of times...

Meaning, if I use the buggy code that doesn't close the db, and connect once, I don't see any "idle" records in the pg_stat_activity table. Mind you, it takes me a second or two to switch between the window that is running the script and the one that has the psql client running.

So here are my questions.

1. What's the best way to track idle connections?  Am I using the right approach?
2. After the postgresql session selects the data I've requested and returns it to the client, how long does it wait before killing idle sessions?  Or, are these idle records getting killed off when my script has finished running through all its logic?

I've tried using TCP keep alives with very low values just in case that's relevant... and I get the same results.

If my question is not clear enough, please let me know and I will revise. 
Thanks

Comment: What I've done in the past is store a traceback (using `debug.traceback`) when allocating a connection or query, and if the program exits or database is closed, if there is an open resource, the traceback will give you where it is allocated.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo would you mind giving me a little example please?  I've been google debug.traceback and taking a look at some examples.. but it'd be helpful if you could show me what you mean.  Thanks.